# Call value from a method inside Main() function

Tags: c#

I am trying to call a value from a method called GetInputstring from inside Main() method, and proceed to the next steps.
I am stuck regards to how I could get the value myInt and move along.

**myInt** (where it has two * around) inside Main() is where it gets the errors.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        GetInputstring(**myInt**);

        if (**myInt** <= 0)
        {
            Write1(**myInt**);
        }
        else
        {
            Write2(**myInt**);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public int GetInputstring(int myInt)
    {
        string myInput;
        //int myInt;

        Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
        myInput = Console.ReadLine();

        myInt = Int32.Parse(myInput);
        return myInt;            
    }

    static void Write1(int myInt)
    {
        while (myInt <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", myInt++);
        }
    }

    static void Write2(int myInt)
    {
        while (myInt >= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", myInt--);
        }
    }
```

Comment: MyInt is your parameter(the value you pass to your method) and it's not initialized. Further you don't catch your return value (which should be myInt)

Comment: http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/

Answer (score 1):

*MyInt* is your parameter(the value you pass to your method) and it's not initialized. Further you don't catch your return value (which should be myInt)

You also need to make your methods static in order to call them from a static method or you create an instance of the class and invoke the method on it

That's how you'll get what you want:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int myInt = GetInputstring(); //MyInt gets set with your return value 

    if (myInt <= 0)
    {
        Write1(myInt);
    }
    else
    {
        Write2(myInt);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static int GetInputstring() //Deleted parameter because you don't need it.
{
    string myInput;
    //int myInt;

    Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
    myInput = Console.ReadLine();

    int myInt = Int32.Parse(myInput);
    return myInt;            
}
```

Comment: I am getting error on GetInputstring(); "An object reference is required for the non-static field, or property".. Also inside method GetInputstring(), getting two errors on myInt: "The name 'myInt' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Have you made your method static? Check my edit, forgot to create an integer: `int myInt = Int32.Parse(myInput);` or you could return the value just when it's parsed with `return Int32.Parse(myInput);`

Comment: You're welcome, but you really should get more into the fundamentals.

Comment: Btw: You really should accept answers to your questions, if they solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your `myInt` variable and store it in the local or global scope. With this variable you will need to set it with the value you get from `GetInputString()` because you are not passing the int as a `ref`  it will not be assigned in the method. You also need to make your methods static so they can be called from `Main` without creating an instance, Ex: `public static int GetInputstring()`

```
int myInt = 0;
myInt = GetInputstring(myInt);

if (myInt <= 0)
{
    Write1(myInt);
}
else
{
    Write2(myInt);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Alternatively (And preferably), you could make `GetInputString()` assign the value because it dosen't need `myInt` to be passed as an parameter.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int myInt = GetInputstring();

    if (myInt <= 0)
    {
        Write1(myInt);
    }
    else
    {
        Write2(myInt);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static int GetInputstring()
{
    Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
    string myInput = Console.ReadLine();
    return Int32.Parse(myInput);            
}
```